# how to display accessibility property in javafx scene builder 2.0

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm using javafx scene builder 2.0, and I follow some tutorials where they use a property called accessibility, but on my version I can't find this property, how to display it please ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Gluon Scene Builder, version 8.3.0 from [here](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/#download).

It contains the accessible options you are looking for, among other new features.

[image: Scene Builder 8.3.0]

Note the old 2.0 version is not updated anymore.